# DateTimeFormatter weekday seems off by one

Tags: java-8, jodatime, java-time, dayofweek, datetime-parsing

I'm porting an existing application from Joda-Time to Java 8 `java.time`.

I ran into a problem where parsing a date/time string that contains a 'day of week' value triggered an exception in my unit tests.

When parsing:

> 2016-12-21 20:50:25 Wednesday December +0000 3

using format:

```
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'EEEE' 'MMMM' 'ZZ' 'e
```

I get:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: 
Text '2016-12-21 20:50:25 Wednesday December +0000 3' 
could not be parsed: Conflict found: 
Field DayOfWeek 3 differs from DayOfWeek 2 derived from 2016-12-21
```

When letting the `DateTimeFormatter` indicate what it expects:

```
String logline     = "2016-12-21 20:50:25 Wednesday December +0000";
String format      = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'EEEE' 'MMMM' 'ZZ";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);;
ZonedDateTime dateTime = formatter.parse(logline, ZonedDateTime::from);

format      = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'EEEE' 'MMMM' 'ZZ' 'e";
formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(formatter.format(dateTime));
```

I now get this output:

```
2016-12-21 20:50:25 Wednesday December +0000 4
```

So effectively the root cause of the problem is that the `e` flag in Joda-Time considers Monday to be `1` yet the Java 8 `java.time` considers Monday to be `0`.

Now for the patterns that `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` supports I find in both [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) and in JSR-310 this:

```
e/c     localized day-of-week       number/text       2; 02; Tue; Tuesday; T
```

This explicit example of `2` and 'Tuesday' leads me to believe that Wednesday should also in java.time be `3` instead of `4`.

What is wrong here?
Do I misunderstand?
Is this a bug in Java 8?

Comment: What timezone/locale are you using, as the doc says it's localized day of the week, some locales start the week of Sunday as opposed to Monday

Comment: To clarify I added the .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH); in the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a difference on how Joda-Time and `java.time` interprets the pattern `e`.

---

In Joda-Time, the `e` pattern [designates the numeric value of day-of-week](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

```
Symbol  Meaning        Presentation  Examples
------  -----------    ------------  -------
e       day of week    number        2
```

So, using `e` is equivalent to getting the day of the week from a date object:

```
// using org.joda.time.DateTime and org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
DateTime d = new DateTime(2016, 12, 21, 20, 50, 25, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("e").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(d.toString(fmt)); // 3
System.out.println(d.getDayOfWeek()); // 3
System.out.println(d.dayOfWeek().getAsText(Locale.ENGLISH)); // Wednesday
```

Note that both the formatter and `getDayOfWeek()` return `3`. The [`getDayOfWeek()` method](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#getDayOfWeek--) returns a value defined in [`DateTimeConstants` class](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html), and [Wednesday's value is `3`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html#WEDNESDAY) ([the third day of the week](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/days/wednesday.html) according to [ISO's definition](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/days/)).

---

In `java.time` API, the pattern `e` [has a different meaning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-):

```
Pattern  Count  Equivalent builder methods
-------  -----  --------------------------
e        1      append special localized WeekFields element for numeric day-of-week
```

It uses the localized [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) element, and this can vary according to the locale. The behaviour might be different when compared to the `getDayOfWeek()` method:

```
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.of(2016, 12, 21, 20, 50, 25, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("e", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(z.format(fmt)); // 4
System.out.println(z.getDayOfWeek()); // WEDNESDAY
System.out.println(z.getDayOfWeek().getValue()); // 3
```

Note that the formatter uses the localized day of week for English locale, and the value is `4`, while calling `getDayOfWeek().getValue()` returns `3`.

That's because `e` with English locale is equivalent to using a `java.time.temporal.WeekFields`:

```
// using localized fields
WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(z.get(wf.dayOfWeek())); // 4
```

While `getDayOfWeek()` is equivalent to using ISO's definition:

```
// same as getDayOfWeek()
System.out.println(z.get(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek())); // 3
```

That's because ISO's definition uses Monday as the first day of the week, while `WeekFields` with English locale uses Sunday:

```
// comparing the first day of week
System.out.println(WeekFields.ISO.getFirstDayOfWeek()); // MONDAY
System.out.println(wf.getFirstDayOfWeek()); // SUNDAY
```

So the `e` pattern might behave differently or not to `getDayOfWeek()`, according to the locale set in the formatter (or the JVM default locale, if none is set). In French locale, for example, it behaves just like ISO, while in some arabic locales, the first day of the week is Saturday:

```
WeekFields.of(Locale.FRENCH).getFirstDayOfWeek(); // MONDAY
WeekFields.of(new Locale("ar", "AE")).getFirstDayOfWeek(); // SATURDAY
```

---

According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-), the only patterns that return a numeric value for the day of week seem to be the localized ones. So, to parse the input `2016-12-21 20:50:25 Wednesday December +0000 3`, you can use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and join the date/time pattern with a `java.time.temporal.ChronoField` to indicate the numeric value of the day of week (the ISO non-locale sensitive field):

```
String input = "2016-12-21 20:50:25 Wednesday December +0000 3";
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date/time pattern
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss EEEE MMMM ZZ ")
    // numeric day of week
    .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK)
    // create formatter with English locale
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, parser);
```

Also note that you don't need to quote the `-`, `:` and space characters, so the pattern becomes more clear and readable (IMO).

I also set the English locale, because if you don't set, it'll use the JVM default locale, and it's not guaranteed to always be English. And it can also be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to specify one, specially if you already know in what language the input is.

---

**Update**: probably the `ccccc` pattern should work, as it's equivalent to `appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, TextStyle.NARROW_STANDALONE)` and in my tests (JDK 1.8.0_144) it returns (and also parses) `3`:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss EEEE MMMM ZZ ccccc", Locale.ENGLISH);
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, parser);
```

Comment: Thanks. This explanation really helps. I have the quoting of all of those fields like this because the expression is generated from a strftime formatted input string. I have to figure out a way to append these values to make it all work right. See https://github.com/nielsbasjes/logparser/blob/master/httpdlog/httpdlog-parser/src/main/java/nl/basjes/parse/httpdlog/dissectors/StrfTimeStampDissector.java#L200

Comment: @NielsBasjes You're welcome, glad to help! I've made some tests and maybe the pattern `ccccc` should be what you need. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `Locale.ENGLISH` Wednesday is the 4th day of week, as week starts on Sunday.
You can check first day of week with

```
WeekFields.of(Locale.ENGLISH).getFirstDayOfWeek(); //it's SUNDAY
```