# Java DateTimeFormatter start week with Monday

Tags: java, groovy, datetime-format

I'm trying to format the current date with DateTimeFormatter and I almost get what I need, but my problem seems to be that days of the week are enumerated from Sunday, instead of Monday. So, for example, if I run below code on Tuesday

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
final LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now()
def DATE = currentTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY'cw'w'd'e"))
```

I'd expect the output: `2020cw10d2`, but the actual output I get is `2020cw10d3`. There's a `localized day of week` pattern in 
[DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) documentation, which is `e/c` option, however, it doesn't seem to change anything in my case. I'm located in Europe (GMT+1) and weeks are enumerated from Monday. Servers I work with are also located in the same timezone, but still, I get the same output on my desktop and my servers. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to enumerate weeks from Monday in DateTimeFormatter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46343732/6509

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the `DateTimeFormatter` a locale with `withLocale`:

```
currentTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY'cw'w'd'e").withLocale(Locale.UK));
```

Or pass it as a second parameter to `ofPattern`:

currentTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY'cw'w'd'e", Locale.UK));

However, the formatter should by default use your own locale though, so it's weird that it does something that you don't expect.

The `UK` locale counts week days starting from Monday, so you can use that instead, if you only wants to format weekdays in this specific way.

Comment: You can directly pass the locale to the ofPattern() method.

Comment: @Olivier I don't really like how it reads... but edited anyway. Thanks!

Comment: withLocale() returns a new object, so passing the locale to ofPattern() saves an instantiation.